# How to use extractall() result to add partially duplicated rows to original dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

#### Please, consider next example:

##### generate data

**UPD:** mask added
**UPD2:** added letters to 'b' column to justify extraction

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'Bob', 'a': '123', 'b': '111'},
                   {'name': None, 'a': '', 'b': '999'},
                   {'name': 'Alice', 'a': '234', 'b': '[555aaa, 666bbb]'},
                   {'name': 'Steve', 'a': '567', 'b': '[777ccc]'}])
print(df.to_markdown())
```

```
|    | name   | a   | b                |
|---:|:-------|:----|:-----------------|
|  0 | Bob    | 123 | 111              |
|  1 |        |     | 999              |
|  2 | Alice  | 234 | [555aaa, 666bbb] |
|  3 | Steve  | 567 | [777ccc]         |
```

```py
mask = df['name'].isna()
m = df[~mask]['b'].str.extractall(r'([0-9]+)')
print(m.to_markdown()
```

```
|        |   0 |
|:-------|----:|
| (0, 0) | 111 |
| (2, 0) | 555 |
| (2, 1) | 666 |
| (3, 0) | 777 |
```

##### result I want

Basically, I want duplicate the whole row except extracted value column.

Do not know what to do with indexes

```
|    | name   |   a | b          |
|---:|:-------|----:|:-----------|
|  0 | Bob    | 123 | 111        |
|  1 |        |     | 999        |
|  2 | Alice  | 234 | 555        |
|  2 | Alice  | 234 | 66         |
|  3 | Steve  | 567 | 777        |
```

Something like `df[~mask]['b'] = df[~mask]['b'].str.extractall(r'([0-9]+)')`

Comment: what if you try df['b'] = df['b'].str.extractall(r'([0-9]+)') since you said you don't need the previous one anymore

Comment: @BluegirlFK well, yes, but it is masked, so this should be done with `df.loc[]` somehow and `df['b'] = df['b'].str.extractall(r'([0-9]+)')` throws an error because of index incompatibility

Comment: What is  `mask` ?

Comment: @banderlog013 - Is mask necessary? If use join it should working like need.

Comment: in that case, maybe you could first explode the column for values separated by comma, to have one desired value to be extracted from each row. This should solve the indexing issue. But the answer sent by Jezrael seems also cool.

Comment: @BluegirlFK explode will work, but for it I need those extracted values as list, like converting `"[555aaa, 666bbb]"` to `[555, 666]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`Series.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) for remove second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('b').str.extractall(r'([0-9]+)').droplevel(1)[0].rename('b'))
             
print (df)

    name    a    b
0    Bob  123  111
1   None       999
2  Alice  234  555
2  Alice  234  666
3  Steve  567  777
```

Solution with mask is possible with reassign non matched values of `b` column in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
mask = df['name'].isna()

s = df.loc[~mask, 'b'].str.extractall(r'([0-9]+)')[0].droplevel(1)

df = df.join(s).assign(b=lambda x: x.pop(0).fillna(x['b']))
print (df)
    name    a    b
0    Bob  123  111
1   None       999
2  Alice  234  555
2  Alice  234  666
3  Steve  567  777
```

Solutions with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with convert values to lists by [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html):

```
mask = df['name'].isna()

df.loc[~mask, 'b'] = df.loc[~mask, 'b'].str.findall(r'([0-9]+)')

df = df.explode('b')   
print (df)

    name    a    b
0    Bob  123  111
1   None       999
2  Alice  234  555
2  Alice  234  666
3  Steve  567  777
```

Comment: Thank you! It solves everything))) `str.findall()` totally awesome!